# Executing program through commandline

Tags: java, command-line, command-line-arguments

I am trying to execute a program on command line having dependencies on external Jar files stored in jar folder.

It can be executed as below.

```
java -cp jar/somejar.jar:. MyProgram --abc xyz
```

Is there a possibility if I can do the same without mentioning the jar files, something like below?

```
java MyProgram --abc xyz
```

Comment: Yes, by setting the `CLASSPATH` environment variable

Answer (score 1):

Set your `CLASSPATH` environment variable to contain `jar/somejar.jar:.`

Assuming Unix/Linux, in a shell do

```
export CLASSPATH=/absolute/path/tothejar/jar/somejar.jar:.
```

Then the `java` interpreter will rely on the environment variable if the command-line option isn't given.